# Regex to remove not repeated spaces

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

I fetch name information from a PDF in python with fitz.

Problem is, most of the informations have spaces to match the background, which give me for example : firstname = "`P I E R R E`" and lastname "`L E  D U C  D E  C O L`".

I need to remove spaces between characters **that are not next to an other space**.

Of course at first I removed all spaces with "`s/\s//g`" but for the name it give me "`LEDUCDECOL`" and I need "`LE DUC DE COL`".

Comment: how can I know it is supposed to be "LE DUC DE COL" but not "LEDUCDECOL" nor "LEDUC DECOL" nor "LEDU CDE COL" etc? You cannot have a regexp for that as you apparently have more rules which regexp can't do

Comment: now I think I got what you want. to make LE DUC DE separated use v = re.sub(r'(LE|DUC|DE)', r"\1 ", v)

Comment: Have a try with [`re.sub(' ( ?)', r'\1', s)`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM9YtqCyo/P8/M7cgv6hEoSiVi6tYwVZB3UfBVUHBRSFUwRlEAdnOCv4KPuoQ2aJUveLSJA11BQ0Fe011HYUi9RhDIFWsycVVUJSZV6JRrPn/PwA) (also see [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQAfYl/1)). It matches a space and [captures](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) space to the *first group*. The capture then gets inserted into the replacement (if there was a space after the space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match a single space  , and in a repeating capture group match optional following spaces which will keep the value of the last iteration (a single space) in the capture group.

In the replacement use the group 1 value using `\1`

```
 ( )*
```

If you want to match a whitespace char, you can replace the space with `\s` but note that it can also match a newline:

```
\s(\s)*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DYiWzf/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/F7uNa1).

For example:

```
import re
 
strings = [
    "L E  D U C  D E  C O L",
    "a        b     c def g"
]
pattern = r" ( )*"
for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(pattern, r"\1", s))
```

Output

```
LE DUC DE COL
a b cdefg
```

---

If you want to match a single space that is not followed by another space, you can use a negative lookahead, and use an empty string in the replacement:

```
 (?! )
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N1j59J/1).

Comment: Great complete answer, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
# doing it with no loop, just regex

firstname = "P I E R R E"
lastname = "L E  D U C  D E  C O L"

re.sub(r' ', '', firstname) + " " + " ".join([x.replace(" ", "") for x in re.split(r'\s{2}', lastname)])
'PIERRE LE DUC DE COL'
```

Comment: @LetzterWille I have edited ouzmoutous's question. Because it was unformatted, the double spaces in his example string `L E  D U C  D E  C O L` were not visible.

Comment: @bobblebubble. Thank you. That was confusing for many i guess.